# Why doesn't <input type="number"...> change value of variable

Tags: blazor

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount" disabled="@(currentCount>10)">Click me +    </button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DecrementCount" disabled="@(currentCount==0)">Click Me -</button>

<input type="number" bind="@increment" />

@functions {

    int currentCount = 0;

    int increment = 1;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount+=increment; 
    
    }

    void DecrementCount()
    {
        currentCount--;
    }
}
```

The problem is: changing the increment value has no effect. It remains 1. Why?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is: changing the increment value has no effect. It remains 1. Why?

it is because the input number control is not bound to the increment variable. In order to bound your input number to the increment variable use the `@bind` directive, as follows:

```
<input type="number" @bind="increment" />
```

Now the input number control is bound to the variable. When you select a number in the control the variable increment will get this number, and vice versa.